# Original Price of child product in order Email

Tags: price, email, sales-order, order-email

I want the original child price in the below file.

> app\design\frontend\MyVendor\MyTheme\Magento_Sales\templates\email\items\order\default.phtml

I try `$block->getBasePrice($_item)` or only  `$block->getPrice($_item)` but is empty or price of parent product

Answer (score 0):

This **$_item** in your code refers to the **configurable product** object. You need to fetch the children's data from the configurable product object. Can you try with the following code?

```
$_children = $_item->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_item);
foreach ($_children as $child){
    echo "Child Price :".$child->getPrice();// This line print the child price.
}
```

//You can print the $_item object using the test.log file as below.

```
$writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Printing Item Data...');
$logger->info(print_r($_item->getData(),true));
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Hi, I get this error "Error: Call to a member function getUsedProducts() on null"

Comment: Can you check the data for $_item using var_dump($_item->getData());

Comment: I send myself the order email to test and it won't let me print the var_dump();

Comment: I have added the logger code in my answer which creates the test log file in the var/log/ folder. Comment above code & place only logger code & check.

Comment: Laminas wouldn't let me print the log, I used the basic magento one and was able to. I will write the correct answer shortly. Thank you very much you have opened my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user Jitendra Patel, I tried a new approach and succeeded.

Here's how to do it

**Print the `getData()` of the `$_item` object**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logger = $objectManager->create(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
$logger->debug('Order item data', [$_item->getData()]);
```

By doing so in debug.log you will have all the `getData()` of `$_item`

```
[
  {
    "item_id": "377",
    "order_id": "136",
    "parent_item_id": null,
    "quote_item_id": "4526",
    "store_id": "1",
    "created_at": "2023-02-03 08:36:38",
    "updated_at": "2023-02-03 08:36:38",
    "product_id": "40088",
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "product_options": {
      "info_buyRequest": {
        "uenc": "aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcuc2lvbGEuY29tL2l0L2ZlbHBhLWNvbi1zdGFtcGEtZnJvbnRhbGUtODA0MTIxNmExMjE2Lmh0bWw,",
        "product": "40088",
        "selected_configurable_option": "",
        "related_product": "",
        "item": "40088",
        "super_attribute": {
          "143": "663"
        },
        "qty": "1"
      },
      "attributes_info": [
        {
          "label": "Taglia",
          "value": "6M",
          "option_id": 143,
          "option_value": "663"
        }
      ],
      "simple_name": "Felpa con stampa frontale-6M",
      "simple_sku": "2500016839246",
      "product_calculations": 1,
      "shipment_type": 0
    },
    "weight": null,
    "is_virtual": "0",
    "sku": "2500016839246",
    "name": "Felpa con stampa frontale",
    "description": null,
    "applied_rule_ids": null,
    "additional_data": null,
    "is_qty_decimal": "0",
    "no_discount": "0",
    "qty_backordered": null,
    "qty_canceled": "0.0000",
    "qty_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "qty_ordered": "1.0000",
    "qty_refunded": "0.0000",
    "qty_shipped": "0.0000",
    "base_cost": null,
    "price": "184.0000",
    "base_price": "184.0000",
    "original_price": "230.0000",
    "base_original_price": "230.0000",
    "tax_percent": "0.0000",
    "tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_tax_amount": "0.0000",
    "tax_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "base_tax_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "discount_percent": "0.0000",
    "discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "discount_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "amount_refunded": "0.0000",
    "base_amount_refunded": "0.0000",
    "row_total": "184.0000",
    "base_row_total": "184.0000",
    "row_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "base_row_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "row_weight": "0.0000",
    "base_tax_before_discount": null,
    "tax_before_discount": null,
    "ext_order_item_id": null,
    "locked_do_invoice": null,
    "locked_do_ship": null,
    "price_incl_tax": "184.0000",
    "base_price_incl_tax": "184.0000",
    "row_total_incl_tax": "184.0000",
    "base_row_total_incl_tax": "184.0000",
    "discount_tax_compensation_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_amount": "0.0000",
    "discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": null,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_invoiced": null,
    "discount_tax_compensation_refunded": null,
    "base_discount_tax_compensation_refunded": null,
    "tax_canceled": null,
    "discount_tax_compensation_canceled": null,
    "tax_refunded": null,
    "base_tax_refunded": null,
    "discount_refunded": null,
    "base_discount_refunded": null,
    "weee_tax_applied": null,
    "weee_tax_applied_amount": null,
    "weee_tax_applied_row_amount": null,
    "weee_tax_disposition": null,
    "weee_tax_row_disposition": null,
    "base_weee_tax_applied_amount": null,
    "base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt": null,
    "base_weee_tax_disposition": null,
    "base_weee_tax_row_disposition": null,
    "gift_message_id": null,
    "gift_message_available": "0",
    "free_shipping": "0",
    "has_children": true,
    "product_option": "[object] (Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ProductOption: {})",
    "wrap_items": [],
    "extension_attributes": "[object] (Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\OrderItemExtension: {})",
    "product": "[object] (Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor: {})"
  }
]
```

Finally `<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getBaseOriginalPrice() ?>` to get the original price of the child product